# Output gallery shortcode as bootstrap columns in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

How do I change the output of gallery shortcode? In post we get:

```
[gallery ids="134,127,109"]
```

And I need something like:

```
<div class="row gallery">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="photo.jpg" data-gallery="gallery">
            <img src="photo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        </a>
    </div>
    . . . 
</div>
```

This has to work within the_content() so the gallery filter function has to be replaced. Found some topics about it but all are way old so the functions changed. Also it will be good if the function will respect the count of columns selected in gallery and change it to bootstrap classes.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: So what have you tried? What functions have changed? I give you a hint: Use the [post_gallery filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_gallery)

Comment: I have tried with remove_shortcode / add_shortcode to use my own function, but old examples tell to copy something from original media.php by specific line but in my file I don't think its right.
Found function get_post_gallery but this is not returning column count I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should help you:

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'bootstrap_gallery', 10, 3 );

function bootstrap_gallery( $output = '', $atts, $instance )
{
    $atts = array_merge(array('columns' => 3), $atts);

    $columns = $atts['columns'];
    $images = explode(',', $atts['ids']);

    $col_class = 'col-md-4'; // default 3 columns
    if ($columns == 1) { $col_class = 'col-md-12';}
    else if ($columns == 2) { $col_class = 'col-md-6'; }
    // other column counts

    $return = '<div class="row gallery">';

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($images as $key => $value) {

        if ($i%$columns == 0 && $i > 0) {
            $return .= '</div><div class="row gallery">';
        }

        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src($value, 'full');

        $return .= '
            <div class="'.$col_class.'">
                <a data-gallery="gallery" href="'.$image_attributes[0].'">
                    <img src="'.$image_attributes[0].'" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>';

        $i++;
    }

    $return .= '</div>';

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Will it overwrite the default worpress filter?

Comment: It will overwrite the default WordPress gallery..just test it.

Comment: @bitWorking I get Notice: Undefined variable: col_class

Comment: @soniamaklouf I edited the post. Now there is a default 3 column definition.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by @bitWorking is very good - I understand it was just a fast hint and starter code so this is not complaining about the missing stuff. I just modified it a little to fix/add the things which bothered me - maybe it will be usefull for someone: [modified code on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/TMMC/696bd0fa164654a9735c1029f8487eaa).

**Fixed/added 'missing' features:**

1. Generating thumbnail size set by user via WordPress gallery panel.

   - Using full size image was waste of bandwidth.
   - If original images were not same size gallery might appear not fine.
   - The CMS user might be confused if he/she set specific thumbnail size and gallery would show different size/proportions.
2. Generating thumbnail `alt` attribute set by user via WordPress gallery panel.
3. Make thumbnails linking (set via WordPress gallery panel) work correctly (none, attachment page, file) to maintain functionality of the panel and not to confuse the CMS user.